# Clone manifest file with JGIT

Tags: android, linux, git, jgit

I'm working in android project with git. In Linux, the command init project is:

```
repo init -u $URL -b $BRANCH -m $MANIFEST_FILE
```

Then i can get the MANIFEST_FILE in ./.repo folder (it includes the source path to build android project).

My code snippet in java application using JGIT is:

```
    try {
            Git repo = Git.cloneRepository()
                    .setURI(REMOTE_URL_SSH)
                    .setDirectory(localRepo)
                    .setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/remotes/origin/build"))
                  //.setNoCheckout(true)
                    .call();
        } catch (GitAPIException ex) {
            System.out.println("clone fail: " + ex);
        }
```

It will download all the manifest file in branch "refs/remotes/origin/build" to my local repo (in fact, this branch has more than 100 xml files. It burns out my memory space, ~ 2GB). I want to get only the xml file that I want like using command in linux above. How can it possible in java application ?

Thank in advance

Comment: Where does your repo command come from?

Comment: I got it from : https://source.android.com/source/using-repo

Answer (score 0):

As you expecting from command line to pull required files, you can follow these commands

Clone Repo:

```
repo init -u $URL -b $BRANCH -m $MANIFEST_FILE
```

To update only required file:

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/$BRANCH -- path/to/file
```

Comment: I mean I want to do the: repo init -u $URL -b $BRANCH -m $MANIFEST_FILE with JGIT in my java application. Is there any API or java lib support it?

Comment: @cuong jgit can only do things the git way. You either need to find a link for your repo program, or execute it manually using a `processbuilder`